# Angular route gets used as parameter from default route

Tags: angular, routes

I have a default route `''` which goes to the HomeComponent of my application. I have another route where you can navigate to with `/other`. Now you can go from anywhere in the application back to the HomeComponent with a parameter `:param`, what happens is: the `/other` route gets used as parameter so it doesn't redirect me but as `:param` I get `other` in the HomeComponent.

```
   const routes: Routes = [
        {path: '', component: HomeComponent},
        {path: ':param', component: HomeComponent},
        {path: 'other', component: OtherComponent},
   ];
```

also tried it as child route

```
const routes: Routes = [
            {path: '', component: HomeComponent,
             children: [
               {path: 'other', component: OtherComponent}
             ],
            },
            {path: ':param', component: HomeComponent},
       ];
```

Is there any solution where I have a parameter on the default route and a child route/ other route?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that order the routes are in is important

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {path: '', component: HomeComponent},
    {path: 'other', component: OtherComponent},
    {path: ':param', component: HomeComponent},
```

];

By moving the route above the parameter it still navigates to the route.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this way:

```
 const routes: Routes = [
    {path: '**', component: HomeComponent},
    {path: '', component: HomeComponent},
    {path: ':param', component: HomeComponent},
    {path: 'other', component: OtherComponent},
```

];